# sparql query house sales property data

Tags: sparql, postal-code

Hi I am using the SPARQL query from http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/qonsole

But I wish to also find out the property type (e.g. semi-detached, detached, etc.), if it is a new-build or not, the estate type (e.g. freehold or leasehold).

The SPARQL query I am using is,

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# Returns the Price Paid data from the default graph for each transaction record having
# an address with the given postcode.
# The postcode to query is set using SPARQL 1.1's 'values' clause

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?postcode {"PL6 8RU"^^xsd:string}

  ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.

  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
}
ORDER BY ?amount
```

Any help would be appreciated!

thank you

Comment: And you don't know how to extend the query or you don't know which properties to choose?

Comment: Yes Im not sure how to extend the query to include this further information.

Comment: I already gave the answer as you can see below.

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't see that, thank you it worked perfectly.

Comment: Could you also shoe me how I extend it further to get the information for whether it is a new build or not?

Comment: Well, it would be good if you try to understand my answer, the principle is the same and ideally, you're able to extend the query by yourself. The first query lists you all available properties. Obviously, `lrppi:newBuild` is the property you're interested in. Then add a triple pattern with this property to your query and select the variable.

Comment: Yes I worked it out, thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this data include ALL historical data or is it limited to specific dates? I would like to extract all data.

Comment: I cannot follow you. I'm not the maintainer of this dataset, I just read your question, did what I always do which in fact is trying to get insights of the schema by running some SPARQL queries and then I extended your query. The query returns everything for the given postal code as you should see. Whether or not the dataset is limited to time series, I don't know. Ask the maintainers, they have a feedback button. By the way, for me it looks like current data and not something historical

Answer (score 2):

To get all available properties, the following query can be used:

```sql
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?postcode {"PL6 8RU"^^xsd:string}

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress/lrcommon:postcode ?postcode ;
          ?p ?o
}
```

Among others, it shows the appropriate properties `lrppi:estateType` and `lrppi:propertyType`. Building the final query is rather simple, just add the triple patterns with those properties and select the variables:

```sql
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# Returns the Price Paid data from the default graph for each transaction record having
# an address with the given postcode.
# The postcode to query is set using SPARQL 1.1's 'values' clause

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category ?estateType ?propertyType
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?postcode {"PL6 8RU"^^xsd:string}

  ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
          lrppi:estateType ?estateType ;
          lrppi:propertyType ?propertyType ;
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.

  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
}
ORDER BY ?amount
```